# Where are Android SDK sources included?

Tags: android, sdk

When building an app with `targetSdkVersion 30` and `compileSdkVersion 31`, which API level sources are included? I think it's `31` or it totally depends on the OS?

Are the sources included in the APK itself? Or these sources are included in ART by the Android System? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Android sources are there in the build process.

There's android.jar on the compile classpath that contains stub versions of the Android APIs. The stubs are enough to build an app with. The real implementations are there on an Android device or emulator.

The version of android.jar matches your compileSdkVersion.

APKs do not have any source code either.

Comment: Hi, So the real implementations are specific to the android OS version?

Comment: Yes, whatever there is in the runtime classpath.